# Dismiss Amazon Fire TV screensaver programmatically

Tags: android, screensaver, amazon-fire-tv

I have a service that launches an Activity and the screensaver is on.
How can I dismiss programmatically Amazon Fire TV screensaver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void turnScreenOn(Activity act) {
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) act.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
    kl.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) act.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

I called this from oncreate() and it works

Answer (score 3):

The First part dismisses the lockscreen, the second part dismisses the Screensaver. However, I don't know if this works with the Amazon Fire TV Screensaver, but you can try it.

Call this method in the onReceive or onCreate Method of your activity.

```
private void wakeUpTheScreen()
 {
  Window win = getWindow();
  win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
  win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
 }
```

I think you also need this permission but I'm not sure:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: it doesn't work, this prevent the screensaver to show up if the app is in foreground